# kamakaketa = having someone spill the beans?

Tags: grammar, words, anime, spoken-language, listening

In Episode 10 of "Kimi wa Houkago Insomnia", MC and love interest's older sister are talking. Older sister (as bait) says she heard love interest had confessed to MC, and MC responds all embarassed, confirming older sister's suspicions. Afterwards, older sister tells MC "that stuff about hearing your confession from my lil sis was a lie: just wanted to get you to spill the beans". In Japanese, the "just wanted to get you to spill the beans" part sounds like "kamakaketa dake", but I have no idea what's actually being said. All I can think of is kamareru (e.g. to have "bitten" the bait), and kakeru (in this context, to have employed/casted something upon someone). But the grammar seems wrong, and I'm pretty sure I'm mishearing what's actually being said. Any help in identifying what's actually being said (and why it means what it does) is greatly appreciated.
Actual clip:
https://i.imgur.com/IgJoT0O.mp4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nvm, literally just found the answer >.<. https://jisho.org/search/%E9%8E%8C%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B

鎌 (sickle/scythe) is a cheeky way of referring to trick/leading questions. And かまをかける is to pose such a leading question.

I'll leave this question+answer up, just in case anyone else happens to have it.

Comment: Thank you, I got curious and I was wondering about the meaning myself. かける is a headache, it has so many meanings even if you disregard idioms.